# Print custom message when WAR is deployed in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, deployment, tomcat7, war

Is there a way to put something in your `WAR` file (maybe in `META-INF`) that will print a customized greeting or message when it is deployed in `Tomcat 7`?

For example, without it, the alert is rather inconspicuous:

```
INFO: Deployment of web application directory myTCdir/myapp has finished in 137 ms
```

In addition to that, I would like to display something like:

```
*******************************************
* Welcome to My App
*******************************************
```

Comment: Define "print".

Comment: To the console it's running out of

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to do that with a context listener.  The contextInitialized() method will be run each time the app starts up.

```
package ....
import ...

@WebListener
public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        System.out.println("*******************************************\n" +
                           "* Welcome to My App\n" +
                           "*******************************************");
    }
}
```

**Note:** *That uses servlet annotations, I don't remember if Tomcat 7 supports it.  If not, you'll have to add it to your web.xml file.*

If you want it to really stand out, you can add color with console escape codes (at least with NetBeans):

```
System.out.println("\u001B[41m This is red \u001B[30m");
```

Comment: Fix these two issues an you'll get an up-vote from me: (1) change `System.out.println(...)` to `event.getServletContext().log(...)` and (2) don't use console escape codes in log files. Yuck.